# «Ни тебе ни мне» — запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, фразеология, частица

Необходима ли запятая? Я по аналогии с *ни пуха ни пера* запятую не поставил, т. к. такое предложение, по-моему, является устойчивым сочетанием.

Контекст: *Забери свою половину! Ни тебе ни мне!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Забери свою половину! Ни тебе, ни мне!**

Д. Э. Розенталь ([§ 62. Правописание частицы ***ни***](https://old-rozental.online/orfografia.php?sid=82))

Местоимения и наречия с частицей-приставкой ***ни*** употребляются в предложениях, где при сказуемом имеется отрицание *не*.
Отрицательное сказуемое может отсутствовать в предложении, но подразумеваться:
*На небе **ни** месяца, **ни** звёзд; **Ни** человеческого жилья, **ни** живой души вдали* (Ч.).

3. Повторяющаяся частица ***ни*** имеет значение соединительного союза:
   *По этой дороге **ни** проехать, **ни** пройти; **Ни** тихо, **ни** громко течёт рассказ.* В этих случаях *ни* по значению равно сочетанию *и не*, т. е. выступает в функции отрицания. Ср. у писателей XIX в.: *Ворон **ни** жарят, **ни** варят* (Кр.); *Елисей был старичок **ни** богатый, **ни** бедный* (Л. Т.).
4. Одиночная или повторяющаяся частица ***ни*** входит в состав устойчивых оборотов.

Широкий список таких оборотов приведен в ПАС под редакцией В. В. Лопатина ([Частица «ни» в устойчивых сочетаниях](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/)).
"Ни тебе, ни мне»; «ни мне, ни тебе» — эти сочетания отсутствуют в этом списке; считаем их однородными членами; ставим запятую.

*Жаль только — жить в эту пору прекрасную

Уж не придется — **ни мне, ни тебе.***
Н. А. Некрасов. Железная дорога

> А ведь дело-то серьезное, молодой Хокинс, и, надо сознаться, **ни мне, ни тебе** оно чести не приносит. Нет, нет! **Ни мне, ни тебе**: обоих нас околпачили здорово.
> Р. Л. Стивенсон. Остров сокровищ

**Ни тебе, ни мне** не станет от этого легче! (А. Петерман).
Это не нужно **ни тебе, ни мне** (Т. Гармаш-Роффе).
Валерочка-то женится на днях, так что **ни тебе, ни мне** не достанется (Н. Александрова).

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, но не думаю, что *ни тебе, ни мне* нужно относить к устойчивым сочетаниям. Я не встречал этого выражения в словарях фразеологизмов. В основном люди пишут через запятую.